# Android Emulator very slow startup

Tags: android

first off, here's my specs, i5 3570 3.40 GHz and an 8 GB ram, but i still don't get why android simulator seems to start a very slow, as of this writing, the emulator is currently loading (starting up) it is almost at the 10min mark, have already downloaded the HAXM, followed the necessary steps in improving the start-up time.. including the use GPU thing. still to no success, it still loads up very slow, just a note this emulator was just created.. so maybe it still loads up everything since it has no previous snapshot.. but that i don't think it would take that long...

Here's the logcat logs for the emulator

```
 05-27 16:25:45.852: E/Installer(2177): connection failed
05-27 16:25:45.862: E/Installer(2177): connection failed
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/Installer(2177): connection failed
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/Installer(2177): connection failed
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177): Unable to write package manager settings, current changes will be lost at reboot
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/packages.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.Settings.writeLPr(Settings.java:858)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:1145)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
05-27 16:25:45.891: A/PackageManager(2177):     ... 6 more
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): Error reporting WTF
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.wtf(RuntimeInit.java:345)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.util.Log$1.onTerribleFailure(Log.java:103)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:278)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.Settings.writeLPr(Settings.java:1022)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:1145)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
05-27 16:25:45.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2177): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/system/accounts.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177): Failed to open the database. closing it.
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.purgeOldGrants(AccountManagerService.java:223)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:216)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:186)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SQLiteDatabase(2177):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:179)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177): Failure starting Account Manager
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.purgeOldGrants(AccountManagerService.java:223)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:216)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:186)
05-27 16:25:45.902: E/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:179)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177): ******************************************
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177): ************ Failure starting core service
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccounts(AccountManager.java:375)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at android.content.SyncManager.<init>(SyncManager.java:379)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at android.content.ContentService.getSyncManager(ContentService.java:55)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at android.content.ContentService.<init>(ContentService.java:134)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at android.content.ContentService.main(ContentService.java:494)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/System(2177):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:186)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/ActivityThread(2177): Failed to find provider info for settings
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): BOOT FAILURE starting Input Manager Service
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getString(Settings.java:711)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getString(Settings.java:2211)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.buildInputMethodListLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:2047)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.<init>(InputMethodManagerService.java:569)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:267)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): BOOT FAILURE starting Accessibility Manager
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1009)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.registerSettingsContentObservers(AccessibilityManagerService.java:294)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.<init>(AccessibilityManagerService.java:173)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:275)
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): BOOT FAILURE making display ready
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.911: A/SystemServer(2177):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:283)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.showBootMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:4051)
05-27 16:25:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:295)
05-27 16:25:45.932: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.audio_flinger',0x4) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:45.932: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.player',0x6) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:45.932: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.camera',0x7) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:47.972: E/installd(2228): Could not create directories; exiting.
05-27 16:25:47.992: E/keystore(2229): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
05-27 16:25:48.202: E/PhonePolicy(2227): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
05-27 16:25:48.941: E/BatteryService(2235): usbOnlinePath not found
05-27 16:25:48.941: E/BatteryService(2235): batteryVoltagePath not found
05-27 16:25:48.941: E/BatteryService(2235): batteryTemperaturePath not found
05-27 16:25:48.971: E/UserManager(2235): Error writing user list
05-27 16:25:48.971: E/UserManager(2235): Error writing user info 0
05-27 16:25:48.971: E/UserManager(2235): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:49.581: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.591: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.601: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.601: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.691: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.861: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.861: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:49.921: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.071: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.081: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.081: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.112: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.112: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.141: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.221: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.231: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.251: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.331: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.341: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.361: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.371: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.391: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.481: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.571: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.571: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.581: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.661: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.661: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.661: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.841: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.852: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.852: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.871: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.881: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.881: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.911: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.911: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:50.971: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.052: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.091: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.151: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.161: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.181: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.191: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.291: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.291: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.321: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.331: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.381: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.381: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/Installer(2235): connection failed
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235): Unable to write package manager settings, current changes will be lost at reboot
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/packages.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.Settings.writeLPr(Settings.java:858)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:1145)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
05-27 16:25:51.411: A/PackageManager(2235):     ... 6 more
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): Error reporting WTF
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.wtf(RuntimeInit.java:345)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.util.Log$1.onTerribleFailure(Log.java:103)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:278)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.Settings.writeLPr(Settings.java:1022)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:1145)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
05-27 16:25:51.411: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2235): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/system/accounts.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235): Failed to open the database. closing it.
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.purgeOldGrants(AccountManagerService.java:223)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:216)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:186)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(2235):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:179)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235): Failure starting Account Manager
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.purgeOldGrants(AccountManagerService.java:223)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:216)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.<init>(AccountManagerService.java:186)
05-27 16:25:51.421: E/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:179)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235): ******************************************
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235): ************ Failure starting core service
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccounts(AccountManager.java:375)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at android.content.SyncManager.<init>(SyncManager.java:379)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at android.content.ContentService.getSyncManager(ContentService.java:55)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at android.content.ContentService.<init>(ContentService.java:134)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at android.content.ContentService.main(ContentService.java:494)
05-27 16:25:51.431: E/System(2235):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:186)
05-27 16:25:51.441: E/ActivityThread(2235): Failed to find provider info for settings
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): BOOT FAILURE starting Input Manager Service
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getString(Settings.java:711)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getString(Settings.java:2211)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.buildInputMethodListLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:2047)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.<init>(InputMethodManagerService.java:569)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:267)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): BOOT FAILURE starting Accessibility Manager
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1009)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.registerSettingsContentObservers(AccessibilityManagerService.java:294)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.<init>(AccessibilityManagerService.java:173)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:275)
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): BOOT FAILURE making display ready
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.441: A/SystemServer(2235):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:283)
05-27 16:25:51.441: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
05-27 16:25:51.441: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:25:51.441: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.showBootMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:4051)
05-27 16:25:51.441: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:295)
05-27 16:25:51.461: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.audio_flinger',0x5) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:51.461: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.player',0x4) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:51.461: E/ServiceManager(779): add_service('media.camera',0x6) uid=1013 - ALREADY REGISTERED, OVERRIDE
05-27 16:25:52.501: E/installd(2286): Could not create directories; exiting.
05-27 16:25:52.501: E/keystore(2287): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
05-27 16:25:52.721: E/PhonePolicy(2285): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
05-27 16:25:53.472: E/BatteryService(2293): usbOnlinePath not found
05-27 16:25:53.472: E/BatteryService(2293): batteryVoltagePath not found
05-27 16:25:53.472: E/BatteryService(2293): batteryTemperaturePath not found
05-27 16:25:53.481: E/UserManager(2293): Error writing user list
05-27 16:25:53.481: E/UserManager(2293): Error writing user info 0
05-27 16:25:53.481: E/UserManager(2293): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 16:25:54.081: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.091: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.101: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.101: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.181: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.372: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.372: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.442: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.585: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.592: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.592: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.621: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.632: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.652: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
05-27 16:25:54.732: E/Installer(2293): connection failed
```

Comment: Have you tried to wipe out the emulator and start it alone without your app?

Comment: I suggest using Genymotion instead of the default Android emulator.

Comment: @bubuzzz yep tried wiping them on start, nothings changed

Comment: @michaelcarrano yep gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable the AVD?

Look at this answer: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow)

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html

Comment: what do u mean enable? do u mean the snapshot or u mean enable AVD? i don't think AVD can be disabled? i don't get ur answer

Comment: take a look to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow

Answer (score 0):

there is something broken, like `/data` not being mounted, did you tried http://www.genymotion.com/?

Comment: hmm will try this.. so far thats been bugging me all the time, why was there so many errors on android while starting up